# Corruption caused by writes to SD Card using FatFs with TI Starterware

Tags: embedded, sysbios

I have test code that starts with a large existing file on SD Card, test.dat, and the test does this:

```
f_open(&fp, "test.dat", FA_OPEN_ALWAYS|FA_READ|FA_WRITE);
f_write(&fp, bufferOfZeros, 4096, &ioBytes);
```

Seems straight forward.

The result of the f_write is SD Card corruption.

I've traced the EDMA on my embedded device to watch [FatFs](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html) read/write requests. The f_open read requests are all healthy, they properly find the file and FAT table.

The f_write starts by reading the first sector into scratch buffer, great. Then it memcpy's the zeros into the scratch buffer, great. After memcpy of 512 zeros, it needs to commit the sector and move to the next one.

It's at this point where the code is confused. It writes that scratch buffer of zeros to the FAT table!!

The offending code in ff.c/f_write() is:

```
        if (fp->flag & FA__DIRTY) {     /* Write-back sector cache */
            if (disk_write(fp->fs->drv, fp->buf, fp->dsect, 1) != RES_OK)
                ABORT(fp->fs, FR_DISK_ERR);
            fp->flag &= ~FA__DIRTY;
```

Here, fp->buf is the sector buffer of zeros, but fp->dsect is the FAT sector (8318), not the file data sector (10240)! Oops. At disk_write() fp->buf matches fp->sect.

Seems like a basic use case here, I am shocked to see this.

I'm hoping someone in the world has anyone dug into a problem like this before with FatFs?

Comment: I would suggest that the "offending code" is wherever `fp->dsect` acquired an incorrect value, and that is not the code you have posted - that may be where it corrupts the file system, but it is not the root cause.

Comment: EDMA ?  Can you clarify.  I have used ELM FatFs on several projects without problems, except when the user supplied disk I/O driver code (i.e. my code) was at fault, or in a multi-threaded environment, the mutex stubs were not implemented and multiple threads access the file-system.  Have you tried opening the file for write-only?  Not as a solution but as an investigation.  Probably worth adding version information, and  any configuration macros you have used.  The current release is R0.11a (after 9 years you might have thought he'd have made it to release 1.0 ;-) ).

Comment: Thanks for input! I trapped EDMA memory transfers to monitor in/out of the SD Card.

Comment: "EDMA" might mean more with some suitable context - such as what chip you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Clifford is correct - it's a problem on my end, and I knew such a simple use case has to work.

I switched the test to

```
f_open(&fp, "test.dat", FA_OPEN_ALWAYS|FA_READ|FA_WRITE);
f_write(&fp, pattern, 512, &ioBytes);
f_lseek(&fp, 0);
f_read(&fp, zeroedBuffer, 512, &ioBytes);
```

This revealed a caching problem. The f_read operation succeeded, and the DMA completed fine, but zeroedBuffer remained unmodified because L0 was not flushed. Therefore, FatFs was seeing a mix of correct values and stale values. I fixed EDMA caching and now it all works.

Another learning, TI Starterware comes with R0.4b. I started with that, and it returned FR_RW_ERROR that was perplexing. I moved up to R0.11a and got much better error feedback.

Anyone know of unit tests for FatFs?

Comment: I believe [ChaN](http://elm-chan.org/profile_e.html) created the code as a hobbyist - as such it is what it is.  I am surprised for that reasons that it is included in the TI StarterWare, although the license terms do not prohibit it.   For commercial development I think it is more than fair that you take care of you own validation.  I hope TI donated to ChaN's efforts.